# Easyphp : msvcr110.dll is missing

Tags: easyphp, msvcr100.dll

I've installed easyphp-devserver on windows 10. When I launch easyphp, the message "msvcr110.dll is missing" appears.

I've searched on internet and found out I must install the Redistribuable Visual C++ for Visual Studio 2015 [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145][1]

After that, I installed Visual C++ and reboot my computer.

But that doesn"t work. There is the same error message.

Have you any idea to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 21):

I assume you're referring to the Windows 7/8/10 VC14 version with PHP 7 support (v16.1.1 at the time of this post).

The EasyPHP Devserver [download page](http://www.easyphp.org/easyphp-devserver.php) states that Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 x86 or x64 is required, which should come installed on Windows 10 already.

What it doesn't mention is that apparently Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is also required, and doesn't come installed on Windows 10. Here's the download link for that one:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Installing the x86 executable got it working for me. No need for the x64 one it seems.

Comment: Thanks, works for me also with x86 version. Solve also the issue I had in Visual Studio Code, perfect.

Comment: Thanks, I use win 10 x64 after installing x86 version of vc++ 2012 the issue solved for me

Comment: Installing Visual C++ 2012 x64 & x86 did the trick! Thanks a lot! It's written nowhere on their website (even in the FAQ about the missing dlls...)

Comment: Worked for me. Don't forget to restart your computer!

Answer (score 3):

As highlighted by Adam C try downloading the 32bit (e.g. x86) version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 it should resolve the issue... as I had the 64bit Win7 installed I tried to use the 64bit Redistributable file and it did not help fix the issue... but, used the 32bit version and vola it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Download and extract msvcr110.dll and then paste it in Windows/sysWOW64 folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).